# What kind of bolt is this?

Tags: screws, removal, bolts

I'm trying to dismantle some wall boards, but I don't know how to remove the pictured bolt - close up attached. 
Its head has the dome shape of a carriage bolt, but there is a hole in the center, with a square-shaped pin deeper inside. Note the hole is circular and not hex, so this is not an allen bolt.
Its a wood-and-fiberglass board attached to a metal frame. I would love to cut up the board, but the metal frame surrounds the entire board, and is attached with these bizarre bolts. Any suggestions or ideas would be most appreciated.
Thanks!

[image: screw close-up]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a [pop rivet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_rivet), not a bolt. It can only be removed destructively.

Drill out the center with a drill bit meant for metal (as opposed to a brad point bit, for instance) until the flange come off. Use a bit roughly half the diameter of the flange.

When the flange breaks free, it will get stuck on the tip of your drill bit, which you will then remove with pliers.

Comment: ... nice prediction of the future...

Comment: ... those who know history are doomed to repeat it...

Comment: so an ordinary drill will work here?

Comment: @AFischbein: Yes an ordinary HSS drill bit of the appropriate diameter. Don't use an ordinary brad-point wood bit or an ordinary tungsten-tipped masonry bit. Getting the diameter right is the key to success for removing rivets. Done right it won't damage the hole.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you want the diameter of the drill bit to be about 1/2 the diameter of the flange.

Comment: @danielgriscom -- when your proposed edits are drastic, I suggest you write your own answer. Happy to discuss further in chat.

Comment: I do think changing "Pop rivet." to "`This is a [pop rivet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_rivet), not a bolt.  It can only be removed destructively.`"  would improve the answer significantly - OP clearly hasn't encountered them before.

Comment: @User95050 My edits didn't contradict your answer in any way, and clearly improved it; you'd even have gotten any resulting additional up-votes. Being proprietary isn't how we work here, as the goal is not to own the best answer; the goal is to collectively result in the best answer.

Comment: The edited version from Daniel is a better, more informative answer.